# List related terms + taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, terms

I have a set of main categories for a set of products. All these products has additional taxonomies associated with them.

On a product category page, is there a way I can get all terms in use for that particular category?

I believe it can be done by looping through all products, but that seems a bit convoluted…

Answer (score 0):

You probaby want [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

WordPress keeps a `count` of the number of posts that use a taxonomy and you can filter your query using it:

```
// get all the terms in the 'category' taxonomy
$terms = get_terms('knife');
// list all the terms that have at least one post
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo "{$term->name} has {$term->count} posts."
}
```

Comment: This gives me all terms in use for the 'category' taxonomy. I want to have all terms in use for that particular taxonomy term, for example 'knife'.

Comment: Yes, change the parmeter `'category'` to `'knife'` ...